# Composer create project error

Tags: php, composer-php

I installed composer using curl and now I try to create laravel project, but I have error after enter command

```
 composer create-project laravel/laravel test-project --prefer-dist                                                                                     
PHP Warning:  Phar::mapPhar(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/local/bin/composer) is not within the allowed path(s): (/srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/webapps/) in /usr/local/bin/composer on line 13
PHP Warning:  require(phar://composer.phar/bin/composer): failed to open stream: phar error: invalid url or non-existent phar "phar://composer.phar/bin/composer" in /usr/local/bin/composer on line 15
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'phar://composer.phar/bin/composer' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/local/bin/composer on line 15
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is different solutions for your problem.

How did you install php ? Are you the admin of your system ?
If so, please edit your php.ini to add /usr/local/bin/ to allowed path in open_basedir.

Comment: In the case of the OP copying /usr/local/bin/ instead of /user/local/bin should be better :)

Comment: After this, I saw the error, but I added /usr/bin/ to the allowed path in open_basedir and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If its helps, I added my /home/user/.composer/vendor/bin/ to my open_basedir option in /etc/php/php.ini

And then also add this directory to my PATH, I don't know if this is secure or appropiate... Works on ArchLinux!

Answer (score 1):

first you have to copy composer.phar "cp composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer" and "cp composer.phar /usr/bin/composer"

after add :/usr/local/bin/composer:/usr/bin/composer to open_basedir option in /etc/php/php.ini